# Html table 'subcategory' to 'category'

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having problems with making one table, what I have done so far:

[image: [table1](http://postimg.org/image/j9ldx93y5/)]

and I want to achieve this:

[image: [table2](http://postimg.org/image/7q93bz2fd/)]

```
<table id="table_groups" align="center" border="1" class="main_table2">

<thead align="left" class="tableheader">
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-decoration:none;"><th colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-decoration:none;">Group</th></th>
    <th rowspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-decoration:none;">Permisions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Ident</th></tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>
<tr>    
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Achieve what you posted? Sorry please elaborate your question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that, my message was not formatted corectly for linking images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="table_groups" align="center" border="1" class="main_table2">
    <thead align="left" class="tableheader">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-decoration: none;">
            Group</th>
            <th rowspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" style="text-decoration: none;">
            Permisions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ident</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that `align` and `valign` attributes are deprecated. For example, `align="center"` should be `style="text-align:center"` instead.